# Why is the set of rationals $Q$, as a subspace of $R$ with the usual (Euclidean) topology, is not locally compact

Tags: general-topology

I know this question is very popular but i couldnt find direct proof by using the definition of locally compactness. Every proof is with sequences. How can we proof this by using just definition of locally compactness?

Comment: What is your definition of local compactness?

Comment: Why would you want to do it without sequences? The fact that you can make use of sequences here is very nice, and makes life much easier.

Comment: I would take a neighborhood of a point in $\mathbb Q$ and show it's closure is not compact by showing that it has a sequence with no convergent subsequence. Is this not what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A\subseteq\Bbb R$, and suppose that $A$ is locally compact. Then each $x\in A$ has a compact nbhd $K_x$. The set $K_x$ has the same relative topology in $\Bbb R$ that it has in $A$, so it is a compact subset of $\Bbb R$ and therefore a closed set in $\Bbb R$. Since $K_x$ is a nbhd of $x$ in $A$, there is some open interval $(a,b)$ in $\Bbb R$ such that $x\in(a,b)\cap A\subseteq K_x$, and $K_x$ is closed in $\Bbb R$, so $\operatorname{cl}_{\Bbb R}\big((a,b)\cap A\big)\subseteq K_x$.

Now suppose further that $A$ is dense in $\Bbb R$. Then $\operatorname{cl}_{\Bbb R}\big((a,b)\cap A\big)=[a,b]$, so $x\in(a,b)\subseteq K_x\subseteq A$, and $A$ is therefore open in $\Bbb R$.

We have now shown that any locally compact, dense subset of $\Bbb R$ is a dense open subset of $\Bbb R$, and its complement is therefore a nowhere dense closed subset of $\Bbb R$. Since the irrationals are neither closed nor nowhere dense in $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb Q$ cannot be locally compact.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\mathbb{Q}$ is locally compact. Then it is locally-closed in the Hausdorff space $\mathbb{R}$. Thus $\mathbb{Q}$ is open in its closure within $\mathbb{R}$. But this is ridiculous since both $\mathbb{Q}$ and its complement $\mathbb{P}=\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ are dense in $\mathbb{R}$.